# How do I use toast in Delphi Firemonkey?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, toast, delphi-xe5

How do I use Android's `toast` in Delphi XE5?

I tried to use the library `FMX.AndroidLike.Toast` but the system is closing during execution before the `Toast` shows up.

Answer (score 5):

I know you know already ... but for others ... just in case.

You need to install the component, add it to the form on which you want to show toastmessages and call ...

```
componentname.now('Your toastmessage string');
```

Do not forget to add the Unit FMX.Androidlike.Toast if you want to use the component based approach.
The component can be pretty much configured in appearance (also the duration how long the message is shown).

If you want to use the JNI approach of Brians unit use Android.JNI.Toast and call the procedure

```
toast('Your toastmessage string', youroptionaltoastduration);
```

You can find the component and now also a link to a screencast on

https://www.cybertribe.de/info/components/fmx/toast/

Answer (score 4):

There's actually an easier way to do it: creating your own toast unit.

```
unit toast_unit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,
  System.Variants, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms,
  FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation;

type
  TToastLength = (LongToast, ShortToast);

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$IFDEF ANDROID}

uses
  Android.JNI.Toast,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  FMX.Helpers.Android;

  procedure Toast(const Msg: string; duration: TToastLength);
  var
    ToastLength: Integer;
  begin
    if duration = ShortToast then
      ToastLength := TJToast.JavaClass.LENGTH_SHORT
    else
      ToastLength := TJToast.JavaClass.LENGTH_LONG;

    CallInUiThread (
      procedure
      begin
        TJToast.JavaClass.makeText (SharedActivityContext,
            StrToJCharSequence(Msg), ToastLength).show
      end
    );
  end;

{$ENDIF}


{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
    Toast ('aha', LongToast);
  {$ENDIF}
end;

end.
```

Comment: [DCC Fatal Error] frmNew.pas(33): F2613 Unit 'Android.JNI.Toast' not found.  Any solution?

Comment: @Pointer use Androidapi.JNI.Widget instead of Android.JNI.Toast

Answer (score 4):

In Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo I use this:

```
uses
  ...
  Androidapi.JNI.Widget,
  Androidapi.Helpers;  

  ...

  procedure TfrmBeaconClient.ShowMessageToast(const pMsg:String; pDuration: Integer);
  begin
    TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure begin
      TJToast.JavaClass.makeText(TAndroidHelper.Context, 
        StrToJCharSequence(pMsg), pDuration).show
    end);
  end;
             
  procedure ...();
  begin
  ...    
    ShowmessageToast('Logged in', TJToast.JavaClass.LENGTH_LONG);
  ...  
  end;
```

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way to create a toast message!

Answer (score 0):

```
unit UI.Toast.Android;

// Java bridge class imported by hand by Brian Long (http://blong.com)
interface

{$IFDEF ANDROID}

uses
  UI.Toast,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText;
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF ANDROID}
type
  JToast = interface;

  JToastClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{69E2D233-B9D3-4F3E-B882-474C8E1D50E9}']
    { Property methods }
    function _GetLENGTH_LONG: Integer; cdecl;
    function _GetLENGTH_SHORT: Integer; cdecl;
    { Methods }
    function init(context: JContext): JToast; cdecl; overload;
    function makeText(context: JContext; text: JCharSequence; duration: Integer)
      : JToast; cdecl;
    { Properties }
    property LENGTH_LONG: Integer read _GetLENGTH_LONG;
    property LENGTH_SHORT: Integer read _GetLENGTH_SHORT;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('android/widget/Toast')]
  JToast = interface(JObject)
    ['{FD81CC32-BFBC-4838-8893-9DD01DE47B00}']
    { Methods }
    procedure cancel; cdecl;
    function getDuration: Integer; cdecl;
    function getGravity: Integer; cdecl;
    function getHorizontalMargin: Single; cdecl;
    function getVerticalMargin: Single; cdecl;
    function getView: JView; cdecl;
    function getXOffset: Integer; cdecl;
    function getYOffset: Integer; cdecl;
    procedure setDuration(value: Integer); cdecl;
    procedure setGravity(gravity, xOffset, yOffset: Integer); cdecl;
    procedure setMargin(horizontalMargin, verticalMargin: Single); cdecl;
    procedure setText(s: JCharSequence); cdecl;
    procedure setView(view: JView); cdecl;
    procedure show; cdecl;
  end;

  TJToast = class(TJavaGenericImport<JToastClass, JToast>)
  end;

procedure Toast(const Msg: string; duration: TToastLength = ShortToast);

{$ENDIF}

implementation

{$IFDEF ANDROID}

uses
  {$IF CompilerVersion > 27}Androidapi.Helpers, {$ENDIF}
  FMX.Helpers.Android;

procedure Toast(const Msg: string; duration: TToastLength);
var
  ToastLength: Integer;
begin
  if duration = ShortToast then
    ToastLength := TJToast.JavaClass.LENGTH_SHORT
  else
    ToastLength := TJToast.JavaClass.LENGTH_LONG;
  CallInUiThread(
    procedure
    begin
      TJToast.JavaClass.makeText(
        {$IF CompilerVersion > 27}
        TAndroidHelper.Context,
        {$ELSE}
        SharedActivityContext,
        {$ENDIF}
        StrToJCharSequence(Msg),
        ToastLength).show
    end);
end;
{$ENDIF}

end.
```

https://github.com/yangyxd/FMXUI/blob/master/source/UI.Toast.pas
https://github.com/yangyxd/FMXUI/blob/master/source/UI.Toast.Android.pas