# Delphi cross platform: how to show a notify text like the one shown when you uninstall an APK?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, notify

I have a text in a listview, I've added an option to copy that text,
now when the user click copy (the text is copied to clipboard), Now i want to show a message that the text is copied of course without using ShowMessage,
i want something like when you uninstall an app, Android Shows a message to the user that 'Uninstalled AppName' and its hides itself after few seconds without any user interaction.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That's called a "toast". There are many examples here on SO of presenting a toast. [how-do-i-use-toast-in-delphi-firemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966611)

Comment: @nolaspeaker I consider your comment is answers my question thanks